# mapItem.openInMaps() unknown location

Tags: swiftui

in my app I have a button that open a destination in maps, the problem is that after maps launching, the destination is unknown location , is possible to make it appear with the name and the information provided by maps?

This is my situation
[image]

and this is what I would do

[image]

that's my code

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import Contacts

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        MapView()
        Button(action: {MapView().openMaps()}) {
             Text("GO!")
        }
    }
}

func openMaps() {
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.928435, longitude: 12.466579)

    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.openInMaps()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name property like -> mapItem.name = "Your Name"